# Generic array to return typed indexes

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Might be a bad question or not even possible but I've been banging my head against it for awhile and cant figure it out. Thanks in advance!

The T generic creates a join type:

```js
const arrayToArray = <T>(values: T[]) => values;
```

When I use the function:

```js
const result = arrayToArray([1, 'hi', 3]);
```

It creates the type:

```js
const result: (string | number)[]
```

I'm looking for it to create:

```js
const result: [number, string, number]
```

---

I'm hoping for `'one'` and `'three'` to return a type error because they aren't numbers.

```js
const useResultType: typeof result = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to get tuples inferred from the array literal, there are two ways to convince the compiler to do this:

Using tuples in rest parameters. This removed the array literal from the call:

```
const arrayToArray = <T extends any[]>(...values: T) => values;

const result = arrayToArray(1, 'hi', 3); //[number, string, number]
```

Using an union of tuple and array constraint to hint to the compiler you want a union. This preserves passing the parameter as an array:

```
const arrayToArray = <T extends [any] | any[]>(values: T) => values;

const result = arrayToArray([1, 'hi', 3]); // [number, string, number]
```

Or if you want a readonly tuple in 3.4 (unreleased yet) you can directly use an `as const` assertion:

```
const result = [1, 'hi', 3]  as const; // readonly [number, string, number]
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks a lot dude! I saw "as const" and was disappointed when I tried to use it and found out that it wasn't released yet! Thanks again! I'll mark your answer correct in 6 min when it lets me haha